# Angular - Modal NgBootstrap ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, typescript

I used modal of ng-bootstrap, i tried to open the modal when a data send from first component to sencons component in the ngOnChanges, but i get the below error:

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed
> after it was checked. Previous value: 'className: undefined'. Current
> value: 'className: modal-backdrop fade show'. It seems like the view
> has been created after its parent and its children have been dirty
> checked. Has it been created in a change detection hook ?

First component:

```
 public openPopup(event): void {
        if (event) {
            this.agreement = event;
        }
 }

 <ef-cp1(openPopup)="openPopup($event)"></ef-cp1>
 <ef-cp2 [agreement]="agreement"></ef-cp2>
```

Second component (ef-cp2):

```
  @Input()
  public agreement: any;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes["agreement"] && changes["agreement"].currentValue) {
      const modal: NgbModalRef = this.initPopUp();
      modal.componentInstance.agreement = changes["agreement"].currentValue;
    }
  }

 private initPopUp(): NgbModalRef {
    return this.modalService.open(NewComponent,
      {
        size: 'lg',
        windowClass: 'modal-adaptive',
        ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title',
        keyboard: false,
        backdrop: 'static',
        centered: true
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

ngOnChanges runs before ngOnInit so you may want to think about what you are doing here - it is difficult to say for sure with your limited info

maybe in ngOnChanges set a variable like

```
agreementChanged = true
```

then in ngAfterContentInit do

```
if (agreementChanged) 
{
 this.initPopUp();
 agreementChanged = false
}
```